# getListUi returns old list view

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-wire-getlistui

I am using following LWC wrapper in aura to get list views:

LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';

export default class WireListView extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @api listViewApiName;
    @wire(getListUi, {
            objectApiName: '$objectApiName',
            listViewApiName: '$listViewApiName'
        })
    listView
    @api get result(){
        return this.listView;
    }
}
```

Aura:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.myList}" action="{!c.listViewChange}"/>
<DecsOnD:wireListView
                aura:id="wireListView"
                listViewApiName="{!!empty(v.selectedView.NamespacePrefix)
                    ? v.selectedView.NamespacePrefix + '__' + v.selectedView.DeveloperName
                    : v.selectedView.DeveloperName}"
                objectApiName="{!v.selectedObject}"
                result="{!v.myList}"/>
```

I've got couple of problems:

1. I need to change v.selectedView.DeveloperName couple for times so that actual record propagates. I suspect this due to how `@api get reusult` works - it returns previous record
2. My change handler fires twice, which is sort of ok, but wondering why - I suspect because I'm passing two attributes?
3. On init getListUi seems to retrieve a list of list views - which would be very useful if I can understand how it works exactly :) ATM I am using SOQL query, but in future I could use this instead.

Comment: "I need to change v.selectedView.DeveloperName couple for times"-- do you mean *four* times? Or something else?

Comment: Meant couple of times. I have a dropdown with list view names that I need to click TWICE so my ui component gets the correct list of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to change v.selectedView.DeveloperName couple for times so that actual record propagates. I suspect this due to how @api get reusult works - it returns previous record

It's caching behavior plus some odd data propagation happening here. You'll want to fire a [custom event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components) for your aura component to listen to, and react accordingly. To do this, use a function with a backing property instead of using the listView property you're using now.

```
_listView;
@wire(getListUi, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName', listViewApiName: '$listViewApiName' })
listView({ error, data }) {
  if(data) {
    const listUpdate = new CustomEvent('listviewupdated', { data: data });
    this.dispatchEvent(listUpdate);
    this._listView = data;
  } else {
    // Choose if you wish to handle or ignore errors
  }
}
@api get result() {
  return this._listView;
}
```

You could even get clever here and dispatch one of two types of events, depending on if you get the list of list views, or if you get a single list view. This might make your logic in the aura component more legible as a bonus.

> My change handler fires twice, which is sort of ok, but wondering why - I suspect because I'm passing two attributes?

Yes, this is expected, normal behavior. It shouldn't harm anything, though you might want to watch out for errors within your component. Notably, if given a choice, make sure you change objectApiName before you change listViewApiName.

> On init getListUi seems to retrieve a list of list views - which would be very useful if I can understand how it works exactly :) ATM I am using SOQL query, but in future I could use this instead.

This is explained on the [getListUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_get_list_ui) documentation. Basically, if objectApiName is not null, but listViewApiName *is* null, you'll get a list of list views. The structure of this is documented at the bottom of the getListUi doc page.

Comment: Hi almost there... Just question wrt custom events - the documentation shows some magic one can grab data by collection name `var filters = event.getParam('filters');`. I am not seeing that... 
I've tried this `const myarr = data; const listUpdate = new CustomEvent('listviewupdated', { detail: myarr });` - I do get event callback but data is not there - tried with getParam detail, data, myarr, etc...

Comment: @dzh According to the docs, it should work. I'll experiment with it after dinner, give me like an hour.

Comment: No worries found the issue by looking at lwc recipes. Pretty sure docs are wrong. This works: `const listUpdate = new CustomEvent('listviewupdated', { detail: {mydata : data} });` and then `var filters = event.getParam('mydata');`

Comment: Taken from https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/ac2e5768461cd0a9c66351bb77ba7384200755fb/force-app/main/default/lwc/contactList/contactList.js#L12
https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/61e1069087da6225cc3efa90cb98f357a84268db/force-app/main/default/aura/auraEmbeddedLWC/auraEmbeddedLWCController.js

Comment: @dzh oh, cool. Time to ile a bug report, lol.

Comment: I do wonder if there is any consideration around CustomEvent size - list views can get huge (they fail somewhat quickly in LEX and work better in classic) pretty quickly. IIRC SF used to recommend passing _events_ thru events and then use attributes to grab actual data...

Comment: @dzh I'm not sure, docs don't say. I would probably read the attribute after getting the notification. That's what I tried to imply with my answer, at any rate.

Comment: @dzh you're missing the object notation surrounding `myarr`. That's important: `new CustomEvent('listviewupdated', { detail: { myarr } })`. Under the hood, it probably creates a new object with the name of the object as a property (a key). Also, big FYI - collections support will eventually come. `getListUi` looks to be an MVP.